# Scrollbar style in css

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I have designed scrollbar for my site.The site width of scrollbar is ok but for the height of it is so long. here is the css code:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 background-color: #263d0b;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar
{
    height: 100px;
     width: 10px;
     background-color: #F5F5F5;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
     background-color: #acff49;  
     width: 30px;

}
```

[image]

I really want to make it short not long like this but I can not set the height of it.

Any idea?

Comment: Can you post html also. Or Create Fiddle for your issue. http://jsfiddle.net/